# Event adapters as inner classes

Tags: java, swing

What is wrong with the following? I have implemented the adapter class exactly as it is shown in a book, but my compiler does not accept his section of code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Eevento{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wumbleton");
      Container content = frame.getContentPane();
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Press this");
      content.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      button1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter{
                                 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                                    System.out.println("button 1 has been                pressed");
                                 }
                                });

      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(500,500);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses after the constructor method for the adapter:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Eevento {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wumbleton");
      Container content = frame.getContentPane();
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Press this");
      content.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      button1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ // parentheses added
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
               System.out.println("button 1 has been pressed");
          }
      });
      frame.setSize(500,500);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```